# How to emulate a smartphone screen on a website selling mobile devices?

Tags: web, frontend, emulation, smartphone

I was thinking about creating a store to sell smartphones, which would have an interactive smartphone in the initial frame of the website. Where the user could test basic functions, such as maps, calls, a social network, just for the user to get a feel for how the device works in practice, before purchasing.Thoughts?

The idea is now just on 'paper', I really still don't know the best way to go.